# How to pass a string if there are more than one server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, cookies, query-string

I am working in a project where it uses two servers. My issue is when ever user clicks a language to select in login page the same language should be displayed in home page when he is logged in. For this they already implemented a cookie to pass the language selection.

It's working in the local machine, but not in the deployed server. Since, the local machine has only one server, but two servers on cloud, when it is deployed its jumping between the servers and not working in the deployed environment.

Then I used query string to pass the language selection. Still it's not working in the deployed server. Guys can any one give suggestions to make it work in deployed environment.

Comment: Well cookies are only on the local machine, so if you go to another computer the setting won't carry. You might want to store the value in a central database.

Comment: Are the 2 servers available under the same name? or is this a www1 and www2 scenario? With just 1 name the cookie should work.